# Edit array list and replace values

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am trying to edit a matrix but am not sure how to do go about it.

I get an out of range error when making num_matrix[col] = 0 and when I just run col = 0 it replaces all of 9 of the values in the row with a single 0. I want all 9 values to each be a zero.

What I am trying to do is make all values in the matrix a 0 and then make it a new matrix.

How should I go about this?

Here is my code so far:

```
num_matrix = [
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
]

for row in num_matrix:
    for col in row:
        num_matrix[col] = 0

print(num_matrix)
```

Comment: Is it a square matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
num_matrix = [
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
]

for row in range(0,len(num_matrix)):
    for col in range(0,len(num_matrix)):
        num_matrix[row][col] = 0

print(num_matrix)
```

**Answer:**

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

The issue with your code is you're taking value directly instead of indexes in col and row.

Comment: This will only work if the number of rows is equal to the number of columns correct? As it must be square matrix, not rectangular in nature.

Comment: It can work for anything as per the requirement. If it needs to be dependent upon the size of inner array then you can just use `len(num_matrix[0])` in th inner loop. Totally depends upon the scenario. Currently I implemented it for square metrix. Do you want me to edit it for a rectangular one?

Comment: Got it. No need to edit it, you have helped very much. Thanks a lot for this.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate using the index value

```
num_matrix = [
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
]

for i in range(len(num_matrix)):
    for j in range(len(num_matrix)):
        num_matrix[i][j]=0
print(num_matrix)
```

Comment: Will this only work if it is a perfect square? Say the number of rows is unequal to the number of columns?

Comment: In that scenario use `for j in range(len(num_matrix[0]))`

Answer (score 2):

This is solution :

```
num_matrix = [
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
]

for row in range(len(num_matrix)):
    for col in range(len(num_matrix[row])):
        num_matrix[row][col] = 0

print(*num_matrix, sep='\n')
```

Explanation:
When you work with 2 dimension list you should get specify which element in which column you want to change [row][col] = 0

Answer (score 2):

Using a list comprehension.  Also clones lists.

```
num_matrix = [
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
]

num_matrix = [[0 for x in y] for y in num_matrix]

print(num_matrix)
```

or

```
num_matrix = [[0]*len(m) for m in num_matrix]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the element providing the two dimensions, row and column:

```
num_matrix[row][col] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` can easily create a matrix, for example

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
print(matrix)
```

gives

```
[[1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]]
```

you can simply use `np.zero_like` to get a new matrix with all 0 values like the original shape

```
new_matrix = np.zeros_like(matrix)
print(new_matrix)
```

gives

```
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]
```

Comment: that is awesome to know, thank you for sharing that.

Comment: In matrix operation, we use ``numpy`` library most of the time. It's good for you to realize it! This solution can be applied into any shape

Answer (score 1):

Modify your loop as follows and you will get your answer

```
for row in range(len(num_matrix)):
    for col in range(len(num_matrix[0]):
        num_matrix[row][col]=0
```